# Combining 'ANDs' and 'ORs' in a complex WHERE query - Part 2

Tags: jdatabase

I have been pulling my hair out with this query for the last 2 days and have read and re-read the 2 other similar posts with no luck.

**Scenario:**
I am gathering two inputs from a user: Test ID Code and email address they used when submitting the test.  The test code is numbers and can have a letter in the beginning, but the testing facility may leave this number out so I add the letter to a variable in the query (reason for "newtidcode" you will see below).  They can also provide up to 4 email addresses to the tester when submitting (reason for me testing on 4 email possibilities).

Here is my query:

```
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('tidcode', 'cdcode','email1', 'email2', 'email3', 'email4', 'status')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__tid_codes'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('tidcode').' = '.$db->quote($tidcode), 'OR')
        ->where($db->quoteName('tidcode').' = '.$db->quote($newtidcode), 'AND')
        ->where('('.$db->quoteName('email1').' = '.$db->quote($email).' OR '.$db->quoteName('email2').' = '.$db->quote($email).' OR '.$db->quoteName('email3').' = '.$db->quote($email).' OR '.$db->quoteName('email4').' = '.$db->quote($email).')');
```

Here the SQL Statement created:

```
SELECT `tidcode`,`cdcode`,`email1`,`email2`,`email3`,`email4`,`status` FROM `#__tid_codes` WHERE `tidcode` = '10348' OR `tidcode` = 'F10348' OR (`email1` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email2` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email3` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email4` = 'someone@fake.net')
```

As you can see the OR before the email should be an AND as specified in the 2nd "where" statement.  I was even trying to use conditions arrays like below and still ran into the same thing.

```
$conditions1 = array(
    $db->quoteName('tidcode')." = ".$db->quote($tidcode),
    $db->quoteName('tidcode')." = ".$db->quote($newtidcode)
);
$conditions2 = array (
    $db->quoteName('email1')." = ".$db->quote($email),
    $db->quoteName('email2')." = ".$db->quote($email),
    $db->quoteName('email3')." = ".$db->quote($email),
    $db->quoteName('email4')." = ".$db->quote($email)
);
```

This is my first foray in JDatabase querying to this complexity.  I have this application working fine in standard HTML and PHP, but trying to port over to Joomla.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're using `AND` in your 2nd `where` clause, but it doesn't appear to be visible in your native SQL statement. It's showing `OR` instead. Is this the issue or purposely done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of `where`, called `$glue`, does not work as you might expect.

This is the source code of the where function:

```
public function where($conditions, $glue = 'AND')
{
    if (is_null($this->where))
    {
        $glue = strtoupper($glue);
        $this->where = new JDatabaseQueryElement('WHERE', $conditions, " $glue ");
    }
    else
    {
        $this->where->append($conditions);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You can see that it only takes the $glue of the first "WHERE" you add to your query.

I found some more information about this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/jFLBSEFCtsU), but the information there may be outdated.

### Solution

Keep your 2 variables, $conditions1 and $conditions2 and then build your query like this:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('tidcode', 'cdcode','email1', 'email2', 'email3', 'email4', 'status')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__tid_codes'))
    ->where(implode(' OR ', $conditions1))
    ->where('(' . implode(' OR ', $conditions2) . ')');
```

Which will result in this query:

```
SELECT `tidcode`,`cdcode`,`email1`,`email2`,`email3`,`email4`,`status` FROM `#__tid_codes` WHERE `tidcode` = '10348' OR `tidcode` = 'F10348' AND (`email1` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email2` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email3` = 'someone@fake.net' OR `email4` = 'someone@fake.net')
```

Comment: Now that I see the "WHERE" code it makes complete sense.  Thank you for steering me in the right direction.  Especially with imploding the conditions, I did not think of that.  I am sure this will help more than just me as I searched high and low and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a bit wordy, but if you ever get tripped up on complex `where()` expressions or don't know about *operator precedence* please read this at least once.

Your question is slightly ambiguous about how the `WHERE` clause conditions should be evaluated. This page is a suitable location to mention [Operator Precedence](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-or/).  Unless otherwise stated, we can all assume that the precedence is working as you require.

However, before I start explaining the impact of that rule, I first want to condense the logic of the 3rd/final portion of your `WHERE` clause (the email matching).

```
`email1` = 'someone@fake.net'
OR `email2` = 'someone@fake.net'
OR `email3` = 'someone@fake.net'
OR `email4` = 'someone@fake.net'
```

...can be written much more succinctly (*D.R.Y.* coding practice) as:

```
'someone@fake.net' IN (`email1`, `email2`, `email3`, `email4`)
```

---

Now I'll demonstrate ***operator precedence*** using that condensed expression.

- `A` will be the `tidcode` comparison
- `B` will be the `newtidcode` comparison
- `C` will be the `email` comparison

> **AND**s are evaluated before **OR**s (see earlier hyperlink)

`A OR B AND C` is the same as `A OR (B AND C)` ...and I think that is what you desire.

If you wanted `A OR B` to be evaluated before `AND C`, you would need to be explicit with parentheses like this: `(A OR B) AND C`.

---

That said, I'll offer two different Joomla-syntax solutions.

**Single WHERE method call**: (a lot of line width, but reads like raw sql)

```
->where("tidcode = " . $db->q($tidcode) . " OR tidcode = " . $db->q($newtidcode) . " AND " . $db->q($email) . " IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)");
```

**Two WHERE method calls**: (reduced line width, but reads less like raw sql)

```
->where("tidcode = " . $db->q($tidcode), "OR")
->where("tidcode = " . $db->q($newtidcode) . " AND " . $db->q($email) . " IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)");
```

Both produce:

> ```
> WHERE tidcode = '10348' OR tidcode = 'F10348' AND 'someone@fake.net' IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)
> ```

---

---

For comparison, **the following snippets evaluate the `OR` first!**:

```
->where("tidcode = " . $db->q($tidcode))
->extendWhere("OR", "tidcode = " . $db->q($newtidcode))
->extendWhere("AND", $db->q($email) . " IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)");
```

and

```
->where("tidcode = " . $db->q($tidcode))
->orWhere("tidcode = " . $db->q($newtidcode))
->andWhere($db->q($email) . " IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)");
```

produce (via `$query->dump()`):

> ```
> WHERE 
> (
> (tidcode = '10348') OR 
> (tidcode = 'F10348')) AND 
> ('someone@fake.net' IN (email1, email2, email3, email4))
> ```

...**BUT**, if you **DO** want to evaluate the `OR` first, then go ahead and repackage the first two conditions of the WHERE clause with `IN` too.

```
->where(
    array(
        "tidcode IN (" . implode(", ", $db->q(array($tidcode, $newtidcode))) . ")",
        $db->q($email) . " IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)"
    )
);
```

which produces:

> ```
> WHERE tidcode IN ('10348', 'F10348') AND 'someone@fake.net' IN (email1, email2, email3, email4)
> ```