# Joomla Select from DB AND / OR grouping

Tags: database, sql

I did not found any guide on how to handle such queries in Joomla:

I would like to select all items from db which are:

```
Published
AND
(the publish up date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 or smaller then datenow)
OR
(the publish down date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 or larger then datenow)
```

to get all items that are published and datenow is within publish start / end date or when setted start/end values are not set.

What I have so far is a simple query:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = 1 ');
$query->where($db->quoteName('publish_up') . ' = ' . $db->quote('0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
    ->orWhere($db->quoteName('publish_up') . '<' . $db->quote($date));
$query->where($db->quoteName('publish_down') . ' = ' . $db->quote('0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
    ->orWhere($db->quoteName('publish_down') . '>' . $db->quote($date));
```

So far so good but in the end it builds up a query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblname`
WHERE 
(
(`published` = 1  AND `publish_up` = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\') OR 
(`publish_up`<\'2021-01-26 13:03:07\') OR `publish_down` = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\') OR 
(`publish_down`>\'2021-01-26 13:03:07\')
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Joomla does not set or group the query as i need it, the first is AND and then everything else is OR.

I'm sure its just a knowledge / syntax gap rather then a bug - but how is the correct way to write a proper query based on my needs?

PS: DB table is from a custom component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `0000-00-00 00:00:00` will always be less than the current datetime stamp, I am understanding your requirements as:

```
published = 1
AND
publish_up <= now
AND
(
    publish_down = 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    OR
    publish_down > now
)
```

- `where()` has a default glue value of `AND`.
- `andWhere()` has a default glue value of `OR`.

To translate that to Joomla's querybuilder you would write:

```
$query
    ->where(
        [
            $db->quoteName('published') . ' = 1'),
            $db->quoteName('publish_up') . ' <= ' . $db->quote($date),
        ]
    )
    ->andWhere(
        [
            $db->quoteName('publish_down') . ' = ' . $db->quote('0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
            $db->quoteName('publish_down') . ' > ' . $db->quote($date)
        ]
    )
```

Your required logic perfectly aligns with the methods' default glues, so no glue declarations are necessary.

Rendered SQL:

```
WHERE
(`published` = 1 AND `publish_up` <= '2021-01-26 13:03:07') AND
(`publish_down` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR `publish_down` > '2021-01-26 13:03:07')
```

Notes:

1. Chaining or not chaining the method calls does not impact the way that the sql is generated.  In other words, you don't gain or lose any parentheses from continuing or breaking a "chain" of method calls.
2. I would be using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` unless your `$date` is not what I think it is.  Like:

   ```
   $db->quoteName('publish_up') . ' <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
   ```
3. Here is [another of my posts that delves into different combinations of where building syntax](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22980/12352).

Comment: its not exactly the query i searched / wanted, but you explained the syntax so its solved, ty

Comment: I want to correct my answer if it is not correct.  Please express what is not yet perfect.

Comment: ok: the meaning is to get every item that has the published to true and datenow is larger then publish_up (this is ok) AND (publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00 (aka not set)' OR publish_down is larger then datenow) (if publish_down is set). Your actual solution would bring up every item because of the publish_up, right?

Comment: I think I understand.  I have updated my answer @Marco thanks.