# Database query with OR WHERE and AND WHERE not working

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm creating a custom search form in Joomla! to search articles from certain categories.

Here is my query:

```
$categories = array('2', '12', '16');
$query
    ->select(array('id', 'title', 'catid'))
    ->from('#__content')
    ->where($db->quoteName('title') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'), 'OR')
    ->where($db->quoteName('introtext') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $categories) . ')');
```

I tried it this way too:

```
$categories = array('2', '12', '16');
$query
    ->select(array('id', 'title', 'catid'))
    ->from('#__content')
    ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $categories) . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('title') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'), 'OR')
    ->where($db->quoteName('introtext') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'));
```

**Issue:** It's showing results from all categories instead of specified categories.

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer, but it would make your question clearer for researchers if you expressed what your desired plain SQL should look like.  This removes any confusion about how the AND/OR logic should be.

Comment: Related insights about `LIKE` [SQL Injections using Jfactory::getDBO and setQuery() with LIKE condition](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352)  Relavant insights about SQL operator precedence: [Joomla Select from DB AND / OR grouping](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28819/12352) and [Combining 'ANDs' and 'ORs' in a complex WHERE query - Part 2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15741/12352)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extendWhere()` method with `AND` as outer glue and `OR` as inner glue:

```
$query
    ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $categories) . ')')
    ->extendWhere(
        'AND',
        [
            $db->quoteName('title') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'),
            $db->quoteName('introtext') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'),
        ],
        'OR'
    );
```

Or the shorthand `andWhere()` method:

```
$query
    ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' IN (' . implode(',', $categories) . ')')
    ->andWhere(
        [
            $db->quoteName('title') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'),
            $db->quoteName('introtext') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'),
        ]
    );
```

The resulting query:

```
SELECT id,title,catid
FROM #__content
WHERE 
(`catid` IN (2,12,16)) AND 
(`title` LIKE '%searchterm%' OR `introtext` LIKE '%searchterm%')
```

Note: to use these methods there must be at least one `where()` call made before.

Comment: Wow! I was struggling hours but I didn't know there are `andWhere` and `extendWhere` available in Joomla! as I checked Joomla! documentation only.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query->orWhere($db->quoteName('title') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $searchterm . '%'));
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help, but please make a habit of including some plain English explanation with every answer that you post.  Your answer was automatically flagged by the system as Low quality. Code-only answers do not typically help researchers to grow.  In fact, if developers know they can come to Stack Exchange to mindlessly copy snippets, we will give birth to a generation of programmers who don't actually know what they are doing.